# Using webpack to use require modules in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, browserify

Tried for the past 2 days to use require('modules') in the browser with webpack, when I could do the same thing in browserify in 5 minutes...

Here's my **webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

module.exports = {
    entry: "./main.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
}
```

However, no matter what I do I get some sort of error. Currently I am getting:

```
bundle.js:390 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "net"
```

and when I run webpack it throws these errors: http://pastebin.com/RgFN3uYm

I followed https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/ and http://www.pauleveritt.org/articles/pylyglot/webpack/ yet I still get these errors.

I've tried to run it with this: `webpack ./main.js -o bundle.js` Yet it still doesn't work.

**How can this be resolved?**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in `webpack.config.js` by reading the `node_modules` directory? I've never seen anyone do that before, and you don't seem to be using the results for anything.

Comment: It's extraneous code right now. I am not sure. Good you flagged that.

Comment: How exactly should I do this then?

Comment: Try including `path: __dirname` in your `output` object (just like they do in the section "A Config File" [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/)). I would also remove the other code so you can rule that out as the source of the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still throwing the same error, though :(

Comment: Edit: var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
}

Comment: Those errors may suggest it is a case sensitive issue in files names you are trying to import. Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin just to exclude this as a source of those errors.

Comment: Just did that, ahh looks like they're still throwing those errors.

Comment: How's moving this into chat?

Comment: @RohitTigga, you should still remove all those imports from your `webpack.config.js` - you don't need them and it's very unusual for them to be included. Have you tried just following the webpack tutorial *exactly* to see if their example works?

Answer (score 3):

You should add directories to resolve e.g.

```
 resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['./app/', './node_modules']
 }
```

**Update:**
Add json loader

```
npm install --save-dev json-loader

module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
    ]
  }
```

also fs, net, tls are libraries for node.js not for in-browser usage. You should add:

```
node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your folder structure?

You should have:

```
packages.json
node_modules/net/
webpack.config.js
src/main.js
```

Then on main.js add

```
var net = require('net');
```

On webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

const PATHS = {
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    dist: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
};

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(PATHS.src, 'main.js'),
    output: {
        path: PATHS.dist,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

Run `webpack`, and this is important, on the index.html, point to the bundle file, not the main.js!

Answer (score 0):

## Node modules can't be run from the browser.

It is, sadly, as simple as that. Let's take a step back. From the [official website](https://nodejs.org/en/):

> Node.js® is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine.

It may seem like a detail, but it is not, *per se*, meant as a JavaScript runtime in a browser. Being a JavaScript runtime however, it can interpret and run javascript code, with added functionnality distinct from what we can do in a browser, for instance the `require()` function. It is built in Node, but not in V8.

What node also allows, is to write modules. You could write a node module in c++, compile it and import it within Node context. This is an incredible strength, because it allows javascript to have access to lower level functionnality, which in turn allowed servers to be written in javascript.

### Low level functionalities are not available in the browser.

Let's consider this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

What is it even supposed to mean, if run in a browser? What filesystem? I daresay that in no event, ever, should I want any random website I consult to gain access to the filesystem of the machine it runs on. In the case of a server, in a Node environment, accessing the filesystem is a necessity.

Node modules, such as fs, tls, or net, use low level functionality that have no equivalent in a browser, be it for logical ("what filesystem?") or security ("no, your javascript code should not be able to create raw tcp connections") reasons.